# Is the gray layer of DensShield easily to be rubbed away? Can I put aqua defense over those?

Tags: bathroom, waterproofing

I've used 4 pieces of DensShield for my DIY project. I found out not only many those are on shelf in store, they already lost the gray layer on edges, also when I unintentionally rubbed the surface multiple times with my gloves, the underlying yellow started to show. If that's how it is, is it okay I paint Aqua Defense or similar over the surface?

Added a photo of the new board I bought last night and hasn’t used.

[image]

[image]

Thank you!!

Comment: You might want to [edit] your question to include a picture of the damage. I used DensShield to do 2 showers and I had zero problems with the grey layer coming off.

Comment: I'll put up photos later. But it is really common especially on the edges when they are still in store. I just saw such yellowish gray edges on the boards in Lowes last night.

Comment: If you are using it for a shower or tub surround, scrap it and use Durock.  If its just wall sheathing in a bath you can Aqua Defense it and tile.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From question 17 of the manufacturer's Q&A at https://buildgp.com/wp-content/uploads/2018/11/DensShield-Tile-Backer-Questions-and-Answers.pdf:

> Prior to the tile installation it is permissible to apply a fluid applied membrane to the face of DensShield Tile Backer for enhanced moisture resistance.

The AquaDefense, RedGard, etc., then, should restore any lost impermeability.